# typescript: type guards fail on union of enum

Tags: typescript

Just read about [`Type Guards`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) Chapter in `Typescript`

But why my following simple type guards fail to distinguish an union of enum?

```js
enum A {
  COMMA = ',',
  PLUS = '+'
}

enum B {
  REAL = 'REAL',
  STRING = 'STRING'
}

function notWork<T extends A | B>(val: T) {
  if(isA(val)) {
    // mark 1:
    console.log('isA:', useA(val))
  } else  {
    // mark 2: 
    // val should be in type B here !!!
    console.log('isB:', useB(val))
  }
}


function isA(token : A | B): token is A {
  return Object.values(A).includes(token as A)
}

function useA(v: A) {
  console.log("we're using A:", v)
  return v
}

function useB(v: B) {
  console.log("we're using B:", v)
  return v
}
```

in my understanding:

1. in mark 1, val is actually in type: `(T & A.COMMA) | (T & A.PLUS)`.
   this works, but why isn't it a simple `A`
2. in mark 2, val is still `A | B`, why is my type guards failed?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUDCB5AspuBeKA5ADTHJQAKAMgKoDKU+BA1AYgL6KKiRQBCCZAEoBRGJQaERY0iloAVQQEkAcgHEJBeUrWsOiAGZgQAYwAuASwD2IKCEumA6pYBOAawA8cqMAAep0AAmAM6wUAA+fAB8ABQAbgCGADYAXFByAJQCKOb60eZBMHFJ6ZlIKCgA9BVQEPFuUACMyWQoxtZBlonAAHSJlgDm0QT5MMnEUGBBwIUJiSVkbN6JUyhl5VU1da5QAEypLVAbs1BBABaWYIkBUABGwFDmNqYAngAO9-ynwM73AIT-BzaIA6XV6AyG+V4YyIEymvCKc3SC3YnAMRjMVhsI2ipksrlAUFScAivHSqVx+KxITgax+pjAzhs6BuACtgGZurMwMAgtEYOluo9jIkwAEeTi8QT4tSkXpDCYLNZYdM4kTSmQgSCen1BgAiADuwAIP1hj36sGSuphsSRKDpDJssRRaIVmOV8NiqVJWSgms62vBBqNJsmZr4luttqg9sZUCdHCAA)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `isA(x) === false` does not imply that `x` is a `B`, just that it's not an `A`.

```
+ 

enum C {
  FOO = 'FOO',
  BAR = 'BAR'
}

+

function notWork<T extends A | B>(val: T) { // yes, not A | B | C

+

function isA(token : A | B | C): token is A {

+
```

Results in the same type error but now it's clear why `isA` does not imply it's a `B` and can't be a `C`.

Your `isA` method could take any union of types as a parameter. It's different from `T` in `notWork`.

Now if you pass both the same type suddenly the compiler *knows* that any `T` that is not an `A` *must* be a `B`:

```
+

type T = A | B

+

function notWork(val: T) {

+

function isA(token : T): token is A {

+
```

[Here's my first playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)
[And the second.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUDCB5AspuBeKA5ADTHJQAKAMgKoDKU+BA1AYgL6KKiRQBCCZAEoBRGJQaERY0iloAVQQEkAcgHEJBeUrWsOiAC4BPAA7AociXAA+fTgDMwIAMb6AlgHsQUEO-0B1dwAnAGsACgA3AEMAGwAucwBKARRXO1DXAGcYCJiEpKQUFAB6IqgISJCoAEZYshQnTwz3aOAAOmj3AHNQgkyYWOIoMAzgbKjovLI2KGBokZQCwpKyiuCoACZ4uqhl8agMgAt3MGiAEygAIzNXLyNTPigD4ECzAEJ37YaQJpb2rp7MrwBkQhiNeDkJgkpuxOIgHM43J4oH1Qvp3MFQFB4nIEvE0RivJlYMkoC99GBAl50BcAFbAFytcZgYAZUIwBKtG5OaJgU4s1HozGRDKwKF6eEuDxeYajCLxdkkr4-NodboAIgA7sACC9QTdOrBYmqQeEoSgyRSvOEYXDHJKkTLweF4rx8mQlc0Vf9NdrdcN9XwjSazaTgOTKVBrRwgA)

Answer (score 0):

Change signature from:

```
function notWork<T extends A | B>(val: T) { // ...
```

to:

```
function notWork(val: A | B) { // ...
```

And it will work as You expected.